# Join 4 tables with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to write below query with INNER JOIN instead of AND

```
select ph.name, ph.position, d.name, COUNT(app.appointmentId)
from physician ph, works_in w, appointment app, department d
where ph.eid = w.physician 
    and d.did = w.department
    and ph.eid = app.physician
group by ph.eid, ph.name, ph.position, d.name
```

.

I tried in this way, But It gets so many errors

```
select ph.name, ph.position, d.name, COUNT(app.appointmentId)
from physician ph inner join works_in w
    on ph.eid = w.department,
    department d inner join works_in w 
    on d.eid = w.department,
    physician ph inner join appointment app
    on ph.ph.eid = app.physician
group by ph.eid, ph.name, ph.position, d.name
```

How can I write it correctly with inner joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me reffer you to [this site that explain all about join syntax's](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Change your query to this:

```
select ph.name, ph.position, d.name, COUNT(app.appointmentId)
from physician ph 
inner join works_in w
    on ph.eid = w.department
inner join department d  
    on d.eid = w.department
inner join appointment app
    on ph.ph.eid = app.physician
group by ph.eid, ph.name, ph.position, d.name
```

The syntax for joins is :

```
SELECT <COLUMNS>
FROM <Table>
INNER JOIN <Another_Table>
 ON(<Relations>)
INNER JOIN <Another_table2>
 ON(<Other Relations>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ph.name AS Name, ph.position AS Position,d.name AS Name, COUNT(app.appointmentId) AS Appointment
    FROM physician AS ph INNER JOIN works_in AS w
    ON ph.eid = w.department INNER JOIN department d 
ON  d.eid = w.department INNER JOIN appointment app ON ph.eid = app.physician
    GROUP BY ph.eid,ph.name,ph.position,d.name
```